# Attaching file for a SAS program

Tags: sql, file, select, sas

I am new to SaS and i tried performing a simple query on sas enterprise guide. 
The program is as follows:

```
libname ISS meta library="SQL - ISS" metaout=data;
  Proc Sql;
    select * 
    from MARKET_OPTION_DAY 
    where contract_market_code = '023A61' 
    and REPORT_DATE between '1/1/13' and '6/30/15';
QUIT;
```

the error im getting is the following : FILE work.MARKET_OPTION_DAY.DATA does not exist.

I dont understand whats wrong because i can view the file in the "SQL-ISS" library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a file is located in a library, then you need to prefix with the library name.

```
proc sql;
  select * from ISS.market_option_day
/* other stuff here ...*/
;
quit;
```

For example.

Comment: thanks . this worked . Also, I have report date in "29JUN1983:00:00:00.000" format and i get an error saying more than one data type. Would you be able to help me out with this ?

Comment: Dates/times/datetimes in SAS are just numbers, not strings. Your `where` clause needs to be along the lines of `datepart(REPORT_DATE) between '01jan2013'd and '30jun2015'd`. The `d` indicates a literal-date-string.